# what triggers the PREADY signal in a slave of an APB?

Tags: embedded, microprocessor, vlsi, soc, amba

I was trying to understand the state machine of an APB. I was curious on how the PREADY signal is triggered low so that it can exit from  the ACCESS state?

If anyone could help me with this basic question, it'll be of great help thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

See page 3-2 of the [AMBA 3 APB Protocol Specification](https://static.docs.arm.com/ihi0024/b/AMBA3apb.pdf). Seems rather clear to me.

And it's PREADY **high** that allows exit from the ACCESS state.